# How to order a Django QuerySet string property numerically?

Tags: python, django, sorting, django-models, sql-order-by

I have a QuerySet, and I would like to order them numerically. The issue is the data is stored as a String. I know how to do this in SQL or a list, but not a query set. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll probably need to fallback to Django's [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#extra) function. Perhaps:

```
ordered = (qs.extra(select={"order_column": "CONVERT(column, INTEGER)"})
           .order_by("order_column"))
```

(Assuming you're using MySQL)

Comment: Thanks Bradley! This looks like it'll work, I'll check it out

Comment: It's the one you're creating, which you subsequent order by.